# Facebook integration with blackberry

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new in Blackberry. I want to post information on wall in Facebook from my application.  I read some documents. What are the steps to integrate with Facebook? Would anyone have a working example Java code for this? How to get api_key,secret_key,application_id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

visit the below link. Here you can download the Facebook SDK for blackberry. also you can download the samples which demonstrates clearly about facebook integration into your native bb app.

[Find Facebook SDK from GITGUB here](https://github.com/chrismoos/facebook-bb-sdk)

Comment: Thanks Neel. I have checked this demo. I may help me. On the first screen, one link is coming named BLACKBERRY SDK DEMO. I clicked on it. It is successfully connected to Facebook. But how to post information from my application to the wall?

Comment: @Nilanchala: I have just download that demo and try to run it with as Blackberry Application (Not as Library) and it give me exception like "NoClassDefenationFound". Please help me towards that

Comment: @Nilanchala: please help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

@krishna Check out the following code. This is basically used to post messages on wall.

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) E.Y. Baskoro, Research In Motion Limited.
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person
 * obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation
 * files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without 
 * restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, 
 * copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the 
 * Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following 
 * conditions:
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, 
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES 
 * OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND 
 * NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT 
 * HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, 
 * WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING 
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR 
 * OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 * 
 * This License shall be included in all copies or substantial 
 * portions of the Software.
 * 
 * The name(s) of the above copyright holders shall not be used 
 * in advertising or otherwise to promote the sale, use or other 
 * dealings in this Software without prior written authorization.
 * 
 */
package samples.strawberry;


import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ObjectChoiceField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.SeparatorField;
import net.sf.blackberry.facebook.FBUser;
import net.sf.blackberry.facebook.FacebookContext;
import net.sf.blackberry.facebook.User;
import net.sf.blackberry.facebook.ui.FacebookScreen;

final class PostWallScreen extends FacebookScreen {

    // List of actions:
    static final String ACTION_ENTER = "postWall";
    static final String ACTION_SUCCESS = "posted";
    static final String ACTION_ERROR = "error";

    // List of labels:
    private static final String LABEL_TITLE = "Post To Wall";
    private static final String LABEL_USERS = "Post wall to";
    private static final String LABEL_NAME = "Title:";
    private static final String LABEL_LINK = "Link:";
    private static final String LABEL_CAPTION = "Caption:";
    private static final String LABEL_CONTENT = "Content:";
    private static final String LABEL_POST = "Post";

    private User[] users = null;
    private ObjectChoiceField objectChoiceField;
    private EditField titleEditField;
    private EditField hrefEditField;
    private EditField captionEditField;
    private EditField descriptionEditField;
    private ButtonField buttonField;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * 
     */
    PostWallScreen(FacebookContext pfbc) {
        super(pfbc);
        setTitle(new LabelField(LABEL_TITLE, LabelField.ELLIPSIS | LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH));

        objectChoiceField = new ObjectChoiceField();
        objectChoiceField.setLabel(LABEL_USERS);
        add(objectChoiceField);

        add(new SeparatorField(SeparatorField.LINE_HORIZONTAL));

        titleEditField = new EditField(LABEL_NAME, "", 80, LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        add(titleEditField);

        hrefEditField = new EditField(LABEL_LINK, "", 80, LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        add(hrefEditField);

        captionEditField = new EditField(LABEL_CAPTION, "", 80, LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        add(captionEditField);

        descriptionEditField = new EditField(LABEL_CONTENT, "", 255, LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        add(descriptionEditField);

        buttonField = new ButtonField(LABEL_POST);
        buttonField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                if (users == null) {
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    users[objectChoiceField.getSelectedIndex()].publishStream(descriptionEditField.getText(), hrefEditField.getText(), titleEditField.getText(), descriptionEditField.getText(), captionEditField.getText());
                    fireAction(ACTION_SUCCESS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    fireAction(ACTION_ERROR, e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        });
        add(buttonField);
    }

    /**
     * Load list of users comprising of friends and self.
     * 
     */
    void loadList() {
        try {
            User[] friends = new FBUser("me", fbc.getAccessToken()).getFriends();

            if (friends == null) {
                users = new User[1];
            } else {
                users = new User[friends.length + 1];
            }

            users[0] = new FBUser("me", fbc.getAccessToken());

            for (int i = 1; i < (friends.length + 1); i++) {
                users[i] = friends[i - 1];
            }

            objectChoiceField.setChoices(users);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fireAction(ACTION_ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I found this code. Where to pass any string from my application in this code? Please help me. Thanks a lot for your support.